# How to parse large xml file in ruby

Tags: ruby, xml-parsing, nokogiri

I need to parse a large (4gb) xml file in ruby, preferably with nokogiri. I've seen a lot of code exampled using

```
File.open(path)
```

but this takes too much time in my case. Is there an option to read the xml node by node in order to prevent loading the file at ones. Or what would be the fastest way to parse such a large file.
Best,
Phil

Comment: https://github.com/ohler55/ox

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try using [`Nokogiri::XML::SAX`](http://nokogiri.org/Nokogiri/XML/SAX.html)

> The basic way a SAX style parser works is by creating a parser,
>   telling the parser about the events we’re interested in, then giving
>   the parser some XML to process. The parser will notify you when it
>   encounters events your said you would like to know about.

Comment: Ok,but how do i read such a large file. AS i said file.open takes too long

Comment: `File.open` is not supposed to actually _read_ the file, but just open a read stream to it

Comment: So would it be possible to read the file by mode Mike file is having the Methode each_line ?

Answer (score 1):

I do this kind of work with [LibXML](http://xml4r.github.io/libxml-ruby/) http://xml4r.github.io/libxml-ruby/ (`require 'xml'`) and its LibXML::XML::Reader API. It's simpler than SAX and allows you to make almost everything. [REXML](http://www.germane-software.com/software/rexml/) includes a similar API also, but it's quite buggy. Stream APIs like the one I mention or SAX shouldn't have any problem with huge files. I have not tested Nokogiri.

Answer (score 0):

you may like to try this out - https://github.com/amolpujari/reading-huge-xml

`HugeXML.read xml, elements_lookup do |element|
  # => element{ :name, :value, :attributes}
end`

I also tried using [ox](https://gist.github.com/amolpujari/5966431)